# ImageView not Showing Some Devices

Tags: android, imageview

I want to show a picture with `ImageView`. But my image size is 618 * 12956.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewKonu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</ScrollView>
```

It looks fine on GT-5830. But snag while sliding with HTC Desire 820. And not show with Note 3. What can I do for all devices showing smoothly?

Answer (score 3):

That image will consume 30.5MB of heap space (assuming the default `ARGB_8888` value for bit depth, which is 4 bytes/pixel). There are plenty of devices where *your whole app* does not have 30.5MB of heap space, let alone a single block that large. Hence, you will crash with an `OutOfMemoryError` on many devices.

You are going to need to use something that only loads in the portions of that image that are needed at any one time, instead of an `ImageView` inside of a `ScrollView`. [Dave Morrissey's `SubsamplingScaleImageView`](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) is one example.

Comment: thanks but it's look http://i.hizliresim.com/MpgnAg.png   but i want http://hizliresim.com/Wk9ML8

Comment: @SerhatHacıoğlu: Check through the [configuration documentation](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/wiki/07.-Configuration) to see what you might need. Even if this particular widget cannot handle it, you will need something along these lines, so you do not load in the entire image at once.

Comment: i could not do anything. The problem continues

Comment: @SerhatHacıoğlu: Then talk to the developer. Or, write your own equivalent of this widget that handles your use case. Or, hunt around and find another candidate library. Or, redesign your UI to not involve a massive image.